# Super Simple Slider not working after AJAX load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to trigger the ready event after the user clicks on `#mail-wrap` which loads in another page with AJAX so that `sss()` can be refired. However, it's not refiring. What am I doing wrong?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    function sss() {
        $(document).trigger('ready');
        $('.slider').sss({
            speed: 5000
        });
    }

    // User event
    $('#mail-wrap').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        sss();
    });

    $('.slider').sss({
        speed: 5000
    });

});
```

Full relevant code (code is surrounded by `document ready` and the `sss()` function is outside of it):

```
(function($) {

    var contactButton = $('#contact-button');

    // Load the Contact page
    function loadContact() {
        $('#content').fadeOut(50, function() {
            $('<span class="loading-icon page-loading-icon"></span>').insertBefore('#content');
        }).load(site.url + '/contact/ #contact-keebs', function() {
            $('.page-loading-icon').remove();
            $(this).fadeIn(50);
            $('body').addClass('contact');
            $('#projects-list').removeClass('fadeInUp');
            $('#contact-info, #clients').addClass('fadeInUp');
        });

        // Change the Contact button to 'Projects'
        $(contactButton).removeClass('contact-button').addClass('project-button').attr('data-title', 'Projects').css('width', '71px').text('Projects').shuffleLetters();
        myIcons.to('work');

        // Change the title of the document
        $('head').find('title').text('Contact | Keebs');

        //Reinitialize SSS
        sssInit();
    }

    // Load the Projects page
    function loadProjects() {
        $('#content').fadeOut(50, function() {
            $('<span class="loading-icon page-loading-icon"></span>').insertBefore('#content');
        }).load(site.url + '/ #primary', function() {
            $('.page-loading-icon').remove();
            $(this).fadeIn(50);
            $('body').removeClass('contact');
            $('#contact-info, #clients').removeClass('fadeInUp');
            $('#projects-list').addClass('fadeInUp');
            TweenLite.to("body.single #project-wrapper", 0.3, {height:0, force3D:true, ease:Power4.easeOut});
        });

        // Change the Projects button to 'Contact'
        $(contactButton).removeClass('project-button').addClass('contact-button').attr('data-title', 'Get in touch').css('width', '96px').text('Get in touch').shuffleLetters();
        myIcons.to('mail');

        // Change the title of the document
        $('head').find('title').text(site.title);
    }

    // User event
    $('#mail-wrap').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Prevent accidental double clicks
        if (!$(this).data('isClicked')) {
            var link = $(this);

            if (!contactButton.hasClass('project-button')) {
                var data1 = { contact_page: site.url + '/contact/ #contact-keebs' };
                History.pushState(data1, 'Contact | Keebs', site.url + '/contact/');
                loadContact();

            } else {
                var data2 = { home_page_contact: site.url + '/ #primary' };
                History.pushState(data2, site.title, site.url + '/');
                loadProjects();

            }

            link.data('isClicked', true);
            setTimeout(function() {
                link.removeData('isClicked');
            }, 500);
        }

    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Are you trying to use [Super Simple Slider](http://supersimpleslider.com/)? Why do you want to trigger ready? Use a function to encapsulate the logic you require and then call in ready and in the Ajax success callback.

Comment: I had to do it with a full page reload when I solved it.

Comment: the .ready callback only happens once. It will not fire after an ajax request.

Comment: $(document).trigger('ready'); isn't possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what your Ajax event does and if you are using `sss()` bound to the jQuery object defining your own function `sss` is confusing. Did you really mean to do something like this;

```
function sssInit() {
    jQuery('.slider').sss({
        speed: 5000
    });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    sssInit();

    // User event
    $('#mail-wrap').on('click', function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       sssInit();
    });
});
```

**EDIT:** You are using [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) so your `sssInit` call will need to go in the `complete` function parameter e.g;

```
   $('#content').fadeOut(50, function() {
        $('<span class="loading-icon page-loading-icon">   </span>').insertBefore('#content');
    }).load(site.url + '/contact/ #contact-keebs', function() {
        $('.page-loading-icon').remove();
        $(this).fadeIn(50);
        $('body').addClass('contact');
        $('#projects-list').removeClass('fadeInUp');
        $('#contact-info, #clients').addClass('fadeInUp');
        sssInit();
    });
```

**ISSUE:** The [Super Simple Slider](http://supersimpleslider.com) hooks up it's events using `$(window).load(function() { ... })` adding elements to the DOM after load will not get the event handlers and prevents the slider working.

Comment: Your code makes sense and I changed my code around to reflect yours but it looks like Super Simple Slider is still not reinitializing after hitting the `#mail-wrap` button. Any ideas?

Comment: @J82 you must have some other code that changes the page to affect what sss will show? What triggers the Ajax event and are you waiting for the async response to complete?

Comment: Clicking on `#mail-wrap` triggers the Ajax event and it's synchronous so I'm not waiting on anything to complete. I'm looking through the code but I don't see anything that would be blocking sss.

Comment: @J82 canpost your full code for the click event? Just add `sssInit` to the Ajax success callback. It will guarantee it gets called at the right time. BTW for jQuery 1.8+ you should use `done` as `success` is deprecated; http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Sure, I posted the full relevant code. I moved `sssInit()` inside the `loadContact()` function. Since I'm using `.load`, I'm not sure if I can use a callback.

Comment: You need the call to `sssInit` inside the `.load` function parameter which is getting called when the url has finished loading. Put it last, similar to where your `TweenLite` code is in `loadProjects`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88143/discussion-between-dave-anderson-and-j82).

Answer (score 0):

> trying to trigger the ready event after the user clicks on #mail-wrap
>   which loads in another page with AJAX so that sss() can be refired.
>
> However, it's not refiring. What am I doing wrong?

`.ready()` already called when `$(document).trigger('ready');` called ?

Try utilizing `$.holdReady()`

```
// do stuff before `.ready()` event called
$.holdReady(true);
// User event
$('#mail-wrap').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();   
    sss();
    // call `.ready()` event by setting `$.holdReady()` to `false`
    $.holdReady(false);
});

function sss() {
    jQuery('.slider').sss({
        speed: 5000
    });
}

jQuery(document).ready(sss);
```

---

e.g.,

```js
$.holdReady(true);
// User event
$('#mail-wrap').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  sss("$.holdReady(true) within `click` event", this);
  $.holdReady(false);
});

function sss() {
  console.log(arguments[1]); // `#mail-wrap` , `document`
  $("body").append("<br>" + arguments[0] + " " + $.now())
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  sss("$.holdReady(false) within $(document).ready()", this)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="mail-wrap">click</div>
```

Comment: I didn't know about `$.holdReady`, and could the downvoter explain why ?

Comment: does holdready work after the dom ready has happened? if not, it's useless for this case.

Comment: @KevinB _"does holdready work after the dom ready has happened? if not, it's useless for this case."_ Not certain interpret "after the dom ready has happened?" correctly ? `js` at above attempts to address case described at OP _"trying to trigger the ready event after the user clicks on #mail-wrap"_

Comment: the entire problem here is this javascript is being added to the page after an ajax request, if i'm interpreting the question correctly. After an ajax request, the domwould have been long ready by then. haven't looked over the code he added yet tho.

Comment: @KevinB Yes, the actual `DOM` may be "ready" , e.g., `DOMContentLoaded` ; though handler `fn` at  jQuery `.ready(fn)` event can be held from being called by `$.holdReady(true)` - even if `DOM` is "ready" , see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.holdReady

Comment: right, but, this part of the question is what makes me think that $.holdReady is going to be called ***after*** the jquery ready has ran. *"I am trying to trigger the ready event after the user clicks on #mail-wrap which loads in another page "*

Comment: @KevinB _"$.holdReady is going to be called after the jquery ready has ran. "I am trying to trigger the ready event after the user clicks on #mail-wrap which loads in another page ""_ ? Yes , this is possible. `click` event can be attached to an element outside of `$(document).ready()` , which could release , or call the `.ready()` event , utilizing `$.holdReady(false)` if `$.holdReady(true)` previously set . `click` event does not have to be attached within `fn` handler of `$(document).ready(fn)` .

Comment: wow, i didn't even notice the `$(document).trigger('ready');` that isn't even possible. that does nothing. the ready "event" isn't a normal event, it can only ever happen once.

Comment: @KevinB _"wow, i didn't even notice the $(document).trigger('ready'); that isn't even possible."_ Not certain if possible or not

Comment: I'm certain it is not.

Comment: @KevinB _"I'm certain it is not."_  Appear `$(document).trigger('ready')` is possible http://jsfiddle.net/56zt9rqc/1/

Comment: @KevinB No , OP is not using `.on("ready")` pattern ; though appears possible to utilize `$(document).trigger("ready")` to achieve same result as `$.holdReady(false)` if `.on("ready")` pattern is used.

Comment: If he switches to .on('ready'), i don't think he needs hold ready.

Comment: But, if he switches to .on('ready'), i'd instead just make it a named function and call it rather than using a syntax that is suggested against in the docs.

Comment: @KevinB Yes , either pattern could be utilized , or a custom event . Not entirely certain what expected result of Question is ? Not tried `sss` ; `js` at above attempts to address OP at _"trying to trigger the ready event after the user clicks on #mail-wrap which loads in another page with AJAX"_ . `.then()` , or `.done()` callback of `$.ajax()` could achieve same result ?